# @ConditionalOnProperty check if a prefix exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this application.yml file

```
 db1: 
   url: ...
 db2:
   url: ...
```

I want to create a bean when the db1 config exists, otherwise do nothing. here is what I tried:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "db1") // this throw error that name or value must be specified
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1")
public DB getDB1() {
   ...
}
```

How do I make it so that the bean will be created when a prefix exists in the property file?

Comment: Raised as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34367

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify either name or value, having just prefix doesn't work.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "db1", name = "url")
```

Or

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "db1.url")
```

Comment: Just FYI. `value` is an alias of `name` so you can use them interchangeably. @Techie probably knows this already. Just wanted to mention it for others who are not as familiar with this annotation.